# Git Bash on Windows 10 ignores Ctrl + C

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash

I encountered strange issue with git bash after starting using Windows 10.

***Sometimes*** Ctrl+C (and Ctrl+X) doesn't terminate running command on git bash
But I can't found any dependency which circumstances related to such bug

What could I do to avoid such issue or to break running command when ctrl+c doesn't help?

Comment: What command are you trying to interrupt?

Comment: I had this pb in spite of command I used: `git push`, `mvn clean install`, `rm -rf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem went away for me after upgrading Git for Windows from 2.23 to 2.37.

P.S. It always helps to include version information in your question.

Comment: problem also seems to exist in 2.24 (just upgraded from that version)

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me when using:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

But it was NOT present with:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

There does not seem to be any difference in behavior between the sh.exe in a folder and the bash.exe in a particular folder. Namely, bin\bash.exe behaves the same as bin\sh.exe, and usr\bin\bash.exe behaves the same as usr\bin\sh.exe

Comment: I used `git-bash.exe` which starts `usr\bin\sh.exe --login -i`, so in my case I have this issue with second one

Comment: Okey, maybe then you can try with the first one

Comment: Good advice, works for me. Used versions - Git: 2.26.2.windows.1, OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue during my maven (3.6.2) build.

When I was checking where the `mvn` command points to in my git-bash it turned out that the unix start script was invoked.
As I'm a bit reluctant to change git-bash.exe to something else (you would never know what else breaks then) my solution was to introduce an alias in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias mvn=mvn.cmd
```

This solved my issue for the moment. Other than spawning a cmd interpreter for the interpretation of the cmd file I did not find any drawbacks of it yet.

Regarding the cause: the `mvn` shell script uses `exec` as its last line, which I suspect as the cause. And this `exec` can only work with built-in git-bash commands; in our case maven execs the Windows `java.exe`.